# Perform printing and saving job sequentially

Tags: java, swing, pdf, printing

I have to print a bill. The bill design has been made using Java `Graphics2D` and some parts of the bill are filled using retrieval of text from Java Applet's `JTextFields`. It's working fine. But what I have to do additionally is, I have to save a copy of the entire printout (not just the contents of the `JTextFields`) as a `pdf`. For testing purpose of the alignment of texts in the printout, I saved it as a `pdf` using PDFXChange 4.0 in the `Print` dialog . But I can't always do 2 jobs - save it first using PDFExchange and print out second in printer. Kindly guide me in regarding how to achieve this in one go using Java.

Comment: I would go about it as 1) Save the PDF to the local disk. 2) Call `Desktop.print(the.pdf)`.  That is not only what you are trying to avoid, but in the reverse order to what you are currently doing it.  OTOH, what is the use-case for combining the two?  *"I can't always do 2 jobs"*  Umm.. you don't have to, it is the code, or rather the JVM, that is 'doing two things'.  That might result in the user 'doing two things' if it comes to security prompts, but again that is not you, but the user.  As to the code, you might have to write two methods, but that is once, rather than 'always'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok Sir. But, can you please make it a bit more clear and exact?

Comment: Will you place some code which you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably try and doing something like send the Graphics2D straight to the PDF using something like iText

Checkout [How do I draw graphics to PDF using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830928/how-do-i-draw-graphics-to-pdf-using-itext) for an example.

You'll have to handle paging yourself.

Alternatively, you could save each page to an image (using the ImageIO API) and insert each image into the PDF

Comment: Sir, Thanks for that idea. I downloaded `itext 5.3.1`. It was a zip file and it contained 10 files and extracted into lib folder of `jdk 1.6.0` . And added the lib folder as the CLASSPATH in system variables. But while I run the program I get the error `package com.itextpdf.text does not exist` similarly for all other packages too . Why Sir?