# Java library to "draw" PDF files

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I'm in the need for a Java library where it is possible to draw, e.g. lines, similar to a graphics context. It should not require XML input, but just a programming interface. GPL or similar would be preferred.

Comment: Use iText , refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830928/how-do-i-draw-graphics-to-pdf-using-itext) for code samples .

Comment: I am in the process of writing a book, entitled [The ABC of PDF with iText](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/) that explains the details of low-level graphics creation using Java. It's quite advanced stuff, so you may want to start with this free ebook: [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/api), which is licensed under AGPL.