# Programming printable 2d-graphics

Tags: graphics, printing, pdf-generation, 2d

I want to create parametric graphics that can be printed exactly on any printer:

- setup some constants,
- create some points,
- create some lines with different line widths and line patterns between those points (a little bit like creating 3d-objects with OpenScad).

A simple example would be to print the net of a cube that can be printed on paper, cut and glued together.

I see following options:

- use a normal programming language like Java and a pdf-creation library (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294987/))
- program using SVG (can this be printed exactly?)

What other options do you see or can you share experiences about the above options?

Comment: as the printers have different DPI then you simply can not print anything exactly the same ... The only thing you can do is print +/- some pixels which is usually precise enough. The only thing you have to be aware of is the printer driver some of the newer ones include (like on HP) feature  for toner savings which shrinks the size to for example 97% and can not be turned off permanently (you can manually change size back to 100% but on next printing it is back) ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a web programmer primarily, so I would create html representing what I wanted printed (in your case, it would require using html canvas element with javascript), and then use an html-to-pdf library to make a PDF. I use PrinceXML, but wkhtmltopdf will also do the trick.

HTML Canvas: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

Prince XML: http://www.princexml.com/